# C# Convert Bitmap to FFmediaToolkits ImageData

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, casting, bitmap, type-conversion

I have standard `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and I need to convert it to `FFMediaToolkit.Graphics.ImageData`. How can I achieve that ?

I tried:

```
ImageData.FromArray((byte[]) converter.ConvertTo(frame, typeof(byte[])),
                ImagePixelFormat.Argb32, frame.Width,frame.Height)
```

but it did just gave me this error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Pixel buffer size doesn't match size required by this image format.
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```cs
private static ImageData FrameToImageData(Bitmap bitmap) 
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(System.Drawing.Point.Empty, bitmap.Size);
    BitmapData bitLock = bitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    ImageData bitmapImageData = ImageData.FromPointer(bitLock.Scan0, ImagePixelFormat.Bgr24, bitmap.Size);
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitLock);
    return bitmapImageData;
}
```